# Apple Push Notification Service is not working after submission, but all good in sandbox

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented APNS in my app, and it works during development. After I submit to App Store, the pop-up does not show, which is used to ask users to choose if receive APNS or not. Anyone can give any idea?

Comment: did you use the correct push certificate for the app store release?

Comment: have you did any change in the certificate after pushing the app to app store?

Comment: No change to the certificate after submission, and correct certificate of course to pass the validation during submission.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would first check that the binary you submitted had push notifications enabled in the entitlements. In iTunes connect view the details for your app's binary:

[image]

You should see the `aps-environment` key with "production" as its value.

[image]

You can also run the following command in the Terminal to get the information from a .app file on your local machine:

```
codesign -d --entitlements - MyApp.app
```

If the `aps-environment` key is set to "production", there is probably nothing wrong with your app in terms of the code. It works in the sandbox environment, so it should work in production (since the code is the same for both). This is assuming your release build is running the same code as your debug build.

In your code, you should be handling the `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` method and NSLogging any errors. This would let you see errors in your device's console.

Since your app is not prompting to enable push notifications, it looks to me like the entitlement is missing. Or push notifications are disabled on the device somehow.

You should also check that your server (provider) is sending the notifications to the production environment (`gateway.push.apple.com`), not the sandbox environment (`gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`). Although if this was the problem, the app would still prompt the user to allow push notifications.

Comment: Thx, Mike, for the very detailed answer. I will try your suggestions, and get back to here. Really appriciate!

Comment: I checked iTunes connect, and there isn't the aps-environment key there. How could that happen?

Comment: How did you build the IPA? If you used Xcode and chose the correct provisioning profile, it should all be OK. Make sure your app ID is configured for push notifications for both development and production.

Comment: The entitlement could also get dropped if you did some kind of manual resigning. Or perhaps the provisioning profile you used was an old version that you downloaded before enabling push notification support. Hard to say really.

Comment: App ID is configured right for both development and production. Yes, I did manually choose the signing certificate. And if I use the old one, is it still going to pass the validation during submission?

Comment: I tried "codesign -d --entitlements - MyApp.app", and I can't find the info of the app file, can you help me with this?

Comment: Problem solved. I opened provision profile by text editor, and found there is no aps key inside, which means it's not enabled. So I regenerated the provision profile, and then it has the aps key there. Thx for your great help.

Comment: Hi Mike, After submit the app in app store push notification worked fine in my app.. but  i have deleted provisioning profile in ios developer portal after some months now not getting push notification.. may i resubmit the app or is possible to enable push notification without resubmit the application?

Comment: By deleting the provisioning profile, Apple will have revoked your push notification certificates. This is why push notifications are not working. You should be able to get it working again by generating a new profile and push certificates for your server.

Comment: i did not get these words ((since the code is the same for both). This is assuming your release build is running the same code as your debug build.)   .... you mean in the "Edit Scheme" do we need to release the Test, Profile, Analyze, Archive ??? or any  ???  Thanks in advance @Mike Weller

Answer (score 0):

your app-id is configured for using apns production-environment in ios portal?

also you can check logs in ur app, it should log apns registration error on specific reason

Comment: "your app-id is configured for using apns production-environment in ios portal?"
Yes, I configured that.
"also you can check logs in ur app"
Thx a lot, I go try this first!

Comment: I checked the log, nothing about my app. BTW, I'm sure registerRemoteNotificateTypes:... is executed, there should be a pop up asking if users want to register for APNS